# Change the color of a grid of cubes in Blender

Tags: python, color

I create the faces of a cubic prism using the following function:

```
def SideXY(data):
grid_dictionary=[]
material_dictionary=[]
position_x=0
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)
flag=bool(0)
for x in range (0,length):
    position_x += 1
    position_z = 0
    for z in range (0,height):
        position_z += 1
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.5, enter_editmode=False, location= 
(position_x, 0, position_z))
        material = bpy.data.materials.new("test")
        tmp=np.array([position_x,0,position_z])
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if data[i][0] == tmp[0] and data[i][1] == tmp[1]:
                flag=1
        if flag==1:
            material.diffuse_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        else:
            material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
            

        
                    
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.5, enter_editmode=False, location= 
(0, position_x, position_z))
        material = bpy.data.materials.new("test")
        tmp=np.array([position_x,position_z,0])
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if data[i][0] == tmp[0] and data[i][1] == tmp[1]:
                flag=1
        if flag==1:
            material.diffuse_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        else:
            material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
            


data=np.array([[1,1], [2,2]])
SideXY(data)
data2=np.array([[3,2],[1,1]])
SideXY(data2)
```

Yet, my ultimate goal is to have certain points of the grid coloured differently. My goal, however, is not achieved . Excuse me if the question is trivial. I have been working on blender only for 1 day. Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to change the Viewport Display color of the Cube?

Comment: Exactly, I would like to visualize the different color choice

Answer (score 0):

##### Assign material to a new Cube and change Viewport Display color

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
obj = bpy.context.object
print(f"Object name: {obj.name}")

material = bpy.data.materials.new("test")
material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
obj.data.materials.append(material)
obj.active_material_index = len(obj.data.materials) - 1
```